# NullPointerException in AVG function with Hibernate SQLQuery

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I want to get the Average value from a Column with Hibernate SQLQuery. I try

```
@Override
    public Double getRating(Long prodId) {
        return ((Number) getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery("SELECT "
                        + "AVG(rating) "
                        + "FROM gio_prod_rating "
                        + "WHERE producto_id = :prodId")
                .setParameter("prodId", prodId)
                .uniqueResult()).doubleValue();
}
```

But when `prodId` doesn't exist in the table, I get a NullPointerException... Then, I try in the controller:

```
Double rating = productoService.getRating(Long.parseLong(idproducto));
        if (rating==null) {
            rating = Double.parseDouble("0");
        }
```

But I get NullPointerException again. I make a debug, and the exception is generated in the SQLQuery. How can I set rating to zero when prodId doesn't exist in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AVG` function returns NULL if there are no matching rows. (cf. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) Calling `uniqueResult()` on it will result in null, resulting in a NullPointerException when you call doubleValue.

This makes sense, as the avg value of 0 values is not defined (0/0 etc...). What you can do is:

```
Number result = (Number) getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery("SELECT "
                        + "AVG(rating) "
                        + "FROM gio_prod_rating "
                        + "WHERE producto_id = :prodId")
                .setParameter("prodId", prodId)
                .uniqueResult()
return result != null ? result.doubleValue() : DEFAULT_AVG_VALUE;
```

or with Java8:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(result).orElse(DEFAULT_AVG_VALUE).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Actually, it'd just be nice to return an `Optional` which could contain a null value.  You'd just then have to check if the value is present if you wanted to use it beforehand - swapping a null check by the producer for an `Optional` check by the consumer.

Comment: @Makoto yeah. Alternatively, skip the null check and Optional altogether, cast the AVG value to double in the SQL query, then return the possibly-null Double directly from uniqueResult() and let the caller figure it out.

Comment: That doesn't sort out the fact that you have to check for some kind of existence of the value somewhere, be it null or Optional.

Comment: Thank you very much , my friends. Without your help, I could not have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

are you sure it's thrown by the sqlQuery? i would guess it's from `doubleValue()`:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29